# Is the FOx TALAS 32 RLC suitable for reasonable jumps, ligh DH?

Tags: suspension, downhill, jumping, fox

Here is the details of the suspension:
[FOx TALAS 32 RLC](http://www.vitalmtb.com/videos/features/Fox-32-TALAS-150-FIT-RLC,2542/sspomer,2)

At the end it sais, that INTENDED USE is XC, AM.

Not exactly sure what AM means, I have a few light enduro trails nearby, and the biggest jump is under 1meter in height.

Could this be the cause that I ruined the bushing in my fork after 3 month(15hours) of riding on these trails?

Thanks

Comment: AM is an abbreviation for All Mountain - basically means up and down as opposed to XC which is Cross Country, less up and down and more flat.  Essentially its saying "this fork is not intended for downhill use" without using those words.  Can't answer your question about the damage sorry.

Comment: Empirical evidence suggest no, it's not suitable for the trails or jumps you are using it for - because it did in actual fact break.

Comment: So a trail bike with the same 140mm suspension is suitable for jumps, but this one is not? Seems quite silly to make such a great travel fork, which still did not allow the rider to clear some drops.

Comment: Any suggestion, on a low budget fork which could easily handle my basic jumping style?!

Comment: Nobody here can tell you why your fork failed. You could weigh 500lbs. You could have drained the oil out and replaced it with Red Bull. You could be a really great rider or a really crappy one. In my view, the trail is never to blame. I suspect abuse, but that's for you to know and for us to speculate about.